# How to Get MSTest OwnerAttribute into Jenkins Report?

Tags: jenkins, mstest

I'd like to get the Owner attribute of our MSTest based UnitTests into the Test Reports at Jenkins (by MSTest Publisher). So it's easy to see at the Jenkins Test Results Report, who is responsible for a (failing) UnitTest.

My test cases look like:

```
[TestMethod, Owner("AAA")]
public void IsItRealTest()
{
    var result = IsItReal();
    Assert.IsTrue(result);
}
```

I already checked the source of the [Jenkins MS Test Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/MSTest+Plugin), that transforms the MSTest TRX Format into a Jenkins readable JUnit format, but I don't want to change the plugin.

Another way would be to write the Test-Owner to stdout like:

```
[TestMethod, Owner("AAA")]
public void IsItRealTest()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Owner: "+ GetOwnerAttributeOfCurrentMethod());
    var result = IsItReal();
    Assert.IsTrue(result);
}
```

But that's not feasible, since we already have thousands of test cases.
So I tried using the TestContext property, that automatically is  set by MSTest.
We already have a base class for all Tests, where I can do the following:

```
    public TestContext TestContext
    {
        get
        {
            return testContextInstance;
        }
        set
        {
            testContextInstance = value;
        }
    }

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Init()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Owner: "+testContextInstance.Properties["XOwner"]");
    }

    //Adding a custom named property for TestContext for all test cases
    [TestMethod, Owner("AAA"), TestProperty("XOwner", "BBB")]
    public void IsItRealTest()
    {...}
```

The problem is, that there is only the XOwner property available at the testContextInstance, but not the OwnerAttribute and I don't want to replace the OwnerAttribute by a custom named one.

Another option would be, to resolve the OwnerAttribute by Reflection and the other information from the TestContextInstance, but that's an ugly workaround.

Is there any better solution, or should I stick with the custom named property solution ?